# How to round an angle to nearest quarter circle

Tags: python

I'm on Python 2.5

I have an angle (in radians). I want to round it to the nearest quarter circle. So, for example:

```
def round_quarter_angle(a):
    pass

round_quarter_angle(3)   # == math.pi (3.1415926535897931)
round_quarter_angle(1.4) # == math.pi / 2 (1.5707963267948966)
round_quarter_angle(6)   # == 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Convert the angle to how many quarters it is around a circle by
  dividing by pi and then 0.5, then use the round() function to round
  to the nearest whole number.
- Calculate the fraction round a circle by dividing by 4
- Multiply by 2pi to convert back to radians
- use % 2*np.pi to find the remainder after dividing by 2pi, so that a full circle (i.e. ~ 6) returns zero.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def nearest_quarter(ang):
    return (((round(((ang)/np.pi)/0.5))/4)*(2*np.pi)) % (2*np.pi)
```

Test cases:

```
nearest_quarter(3)
Out[37]: 3.141592653589793

nearest_quarter(1.4)
Out[38]: 1.5707963267948966

nearest_quarter(6)
Out[39]: 0.0
```